# How do you read from a multidimensional variant array returned from a COM object in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, variant, comobject

I'm working with a COM object that returns a multidimensional VARIANT array (vt_array), and I'm trying to read values from the array.

When I use `print_r($mdArray)` it displays `variant Object`. 
(`variant_get_type($mdArray)` returns `8204`.)

I tried using `foreach ($mdArray as $oneArray)` but I get the message:

> Warning: Loader::getfields() [loader.getfields]: Can only handle
>   single dimension variant arrays (this
>   array has 2) in
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\root\script\fileloader.php
>   on line 135 Fatal error: Uncaught
>   exception 'Exception' with message
>   'Object of type variant did not create
>   an Iterator' in
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\root\script\fileloader.php:135
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\root\script\fileloader.php(135):
>   Loader::getfields() #1
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\root\testloader.php(21):
>   Loader->getfields() #2 {main} thrown
>   in
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\root\script\fileloader.php
>   on line 135

(The foreach loop is on line 135)

The only information I can get about the array is by using `count($mdArray)` which returns `8`.

If anyone here has any experience reading from multidimensional VARIANT arrays please tell me how this can be done.

Comment: do you know the exact class/type of the array from whichever language the com object is written in?  Already I fear you may have to try parsing the array in VB... Hint: `$vb_control = new COM("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl");`

Comment: also have you tried a `for ($x=0; $x < count($mdArray); $x++) $oneArray = $mdArray[$x];` loop instead?

Comment: I tried $oneArray = $mdArray[0] and the whole script crashed with this messsage:
FastCGI Error
The FastCGI Handler was unable to process the request.

Error Details:

    * The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
    * Error Number: -2147467259 (0x80004005).
    * Error Description: Unspecified error

HTTP Error 500 - Server Error.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

Comment: The only thing I know about it is that it's a multidimensional array and each individual array contains 2 strings. I don't know how the array was implemented or the class/type used to create the array. I'm new at this job and I'm' trying to use a COM object that was programmed by someone who left the company and whom I cannot contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to extract array values through "VBScript".  Yes, you read that right...

```
<?php

$com = new COM("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl");
$com->Language = 'VBScript';
$com->AllowUI = false;
$com->AddCode('
    Function getArrayVal(arr, indexX, indexY)
        getArrayVal = arr(indexX, indexY)
    End Function
');

$y1 = 0;
$y2 = 1;
for ($x=0; $x < count($mdArray); $x++) {
    echo $com->Run('getArrayVal', $mdArray, $x, $y1) . ": ";
    echo $com->Run('getArrayVal', $mdArray, $x, $y2) . "\n";
    }

?>
```

Tested good on a VBScript-created array, which otherwise gave me the exact same issues and errors as you when trying to coerce it to behave like a PHP array.  The above method spawned by the unholy union of PHP and VBscript should extract values piece by piece just fine.

To explain `$y1 = 0; $y2 = 1;`, keep in mind the parameters of the VBScript function are byref, so you can't pass anything in except a variable.

**Edit:** Added `$com->AllowUI = false` to shut off any on-screen popups.  Otherwise it would freeze the request if a `MsgBox()` somehow got called from VBScript and no one was at the server terminal to click 'ok'.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you so much! This code worked great. (I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but I really appreciate it.)
Is it possible to reverse this script so I can create multidimensional arrays to send to a COM object?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, you run into the same problem when going in reverse.  You can however foeach loop over it in VBScript.  The only thing I can think of is making a VBScript function to 1) take in a PHP multidimensional array, 2) use nested foreach loops over it building a completely new valid array, 3) return that to PHP to then be returned to your COM object.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer your answer gave me an idea of how to go about a scenario of this type. I have a COM object in Php returning object(variant)#3(0){ } when I issue var_dump($myArrayObject); how would I handle this one?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer would you mind helping me with this Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166123/how-to-loop-thru-and-output-values-of-a-variant-array-object-in-php