# SQL return "variant Object" how to convert to regular data

Tags: php, sql

im a web developer but i dont know much about sql, now i can connect to the server no problem but it returns

```
variant Object
```

but in the db that info has data values. how can i convert it?

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] =>      .0000
        [1] => 70042
        [2] => POLLERA LERGA C/CUERO EN CINTO
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 28
        [5] => variant Object

        [6] => INV02
        [7] => 
        [8] =>  
        [9] => variant Object

        [10] => variant Object

        [11] => variant Object

    )
```

by the way I'm doing the connection with ADODB.Connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to put

```
(string)
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.variant.php):

> The VARIANT is COM's equivalent of the PHP zval; it is a structure
>   that can contain a value with a range of different possible types. The
>   VARIANT class provided by the COM extension allows you to have more
>   control over the way that PHP passes values to and from COM.

And:

> PHP 5 takes a much simpler approach to handling VARIANTs; when
>   returning a value or fetching a variant property, the variant is
>   converted to a PHP value only when there is a direct mapping between
>   the types that would not result in a loss of information. In all other
>   cases, the result is returned as an instance of the VARIANT class. **You
>   can force PHP to convert or evaluate the variant as a PHP native type
>   by using a casting operator explicitly, or implicitly casting to a
>   string by printing it**. You may use the wide range of variant functions
>   to perform arithmetic operations on variants without forcing a
>   conversion or risking a loss of data.

You didn't post code but this means that you can normally just print it:

```
echo $result;
```

Comment: Álvaro González how would you suggest I go about this question I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295574/how-to-convert-8209-array-object-variant-to-vt-variant

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this for help - i used it as a way of processing variants in php. [How do you read from a multidimensional variant array returned from a COM object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800728/how-do-you-read-from-a-multidimensional-variant-array-returned-from-a-com-object)

Answer (score 0):

I've wrestled with this issue for a while and found a solution which worked for me. So let say wee need to return a records set of four values per row from the MSSQL database through ADODB. **It all boils down where you cast the datatype!** If you cast the datatype before copying the (variant) values into the variable of your choice (mostly some array) it will work.

**Example:**

```
$buffer = array();

$sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM tbl_mydata WHERE col1 > 100";

$rec = OpenRecordset($sql); // connect to db, make your own!

while (!$rec->EOF){

    $buffer[] = array((string)$rec->fields[0], (string)$rec->fields[1], (string)$rec->fields[2], (string)$rec->fields[3]);

    $rec->MoveNext();
}

closeRecordset($rec);
```

for the ADOdb docs see here the manual(http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:userguide:userguide_index)

Now your **$buffer** array is ready with string type values.

```
foreach($buffer as ..... blabla...
```