# How to loop thru and output values of a variant array object in Php

Tags: php, variant, comobject

In my Php code I have an array object $myArrayIbject that I want to get its values. I know it is not a one dimensional array. That's what I know for sure.

When I run

```
echo gettype($myArrayIbject);
```

It returns Object.

When I run

```
echo count($myArrayIbject);
```

It returns 1632.

When I run

```
var_dump( $myArrayIbject);
```

It returns

object(variant)#3(0){ }

When I run

```
variant_get_type($myArrayIbject)
```

It returns 8209.

The other thing I have observed is that from $myArrayIbject[0] all the way to  $myArrayIbject[1631] it returns integer values when I run the below code

```
for ($i=0; $i< count($myArrayIbject); $i++) {
     echo "Value at ".$i." is ". $myArrayIbject[$i]."<br/>";
}
```

I know this is not the way to access all its values. I am looking for a way to extract and access all its values.

Comment: you have to show real output of `var_dump($myArrayIbject);`

Comment: It outputs object(variant)#3(0){ }

Comment: Would this be from a COM object on windows? maybe interesting? http://php.net/manual/en/class.variant.php. If not please supply PHP version and operating system and How you created that object? I am curious, The `linked` question in the column on the right hand side of this page may be useful.

Comment: Yes indeed it is from a COM object. Which question on the right? Share the link I will read thru it?

Comment: maybe interesting? accessing array properties in a COM Variant? http://php.net/manual/en/com.examples.arrays.php also: http://php.net/manual/en/com.examples.foreach.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
foreach($myArrayIbject as $index=>$value)
     echo "Value at ".$index." is ". $value."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Gives me ?ž?????????????????????+??????????????????????????????????????????d???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????¹?????????????????????????????????????????????o?????????????????????????C????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????-???????????o????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????´??????????? same as when I do echo $myArrayIbject;