# Why doesn't count($var) = 0 indicate the variable is empty?

Tags: php

I have a variable `$outvar` that is returned from a call to a COM object.  The following,

```
echo count($outvar)
```

returns a value of `0`.

But if I

```
echo $outvar[1][1];
```

the value that I expect to be passed back by the COM object is printed.

Why doesn't a count of 0 indicate that there is nothing in the variable?

(Note: I believe `$outvar` is a VARIANT containing 2 numbers, although I cannot be sure.  This question is related to another question specifically regarding [Displaying contents of VARIANT in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123083/displaying-contents-of-variant-in-php), that is yet to be answered.)

Comment: what is the content of $outvar?

Comment: Can you show us the result of this: `var_dump($outvar)`

Comment: @Fast Snail - unfortunately I can't show you the content of `$outvar`.  My other question that I link to specifically deals with me not being able to view the variable contents (which I cannot do, except for the first element which I can view using the 2nd code line in the question).

Comment: @Karkouch - the output of `var_dump($outvar)` is `object(variant)#2 (0) { }`.